# React: Need help changing the data and html used on click of looped through data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am new to react and now rewriting my personal web portfolio to learn it better. I'm having trouble getting the detail view to show for each project. When you click div className="view" I would like a detail page to call the json in say web.subContent with it's images and  subtitle.

Currently when you click the li in nav id="nav" I get the state of the page to change and the content changes the top level json from web to print or photo in data.json.

Im sure I'm doing a lot wrong here and would love any help I can get in making this work correctly. Here is a link to all the code in my github. https://github.com/fitzmx6/reactportfolio/tree/master/coryfitzpatrick

content.js

```
import React from 'react';
import portfolioData from '../data/data.json';

export default class Content extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {activeCategory: portfolioData.web};
    }

    render() {
        var mainContent;
        if (this.state.activeCategory === portfolioData.contact) {
            mainContent = <div className="content">
                <div className="grid-d-12">
                    <h1>Contact Me</h1>
                    <p>Bio Here...</p>
                </div>
            </div>;
        } else {
            mainContent = <div className="content">
                {this.state.activeCategory.map(category => (
                   <div className="grid-d-4 grid-t-6 grid-panel cs-style-3">
                        <a href="/">
                            <figure>
                                <img src={category.imagePath} title={category.imageTitle} alt={category.name} />

                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2>{category.name}</h2>
                                    <div className="view">View</div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        } 
        // else {
        //     mainContent = <div className="content">
        //        <div className="grid-12">
        //             <h1>portfolioData.web[0].subContent.subtitle</h1>
        //         </div>
        //    </div>
        // }

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="header">
                    <div className="grid-d-12">
                        <div id="logo">
                            <a href="/">
                                <h1>Cory Fitzpatrick |</h1>
                                <h2>Web Developer</h2>
                            </a> 
                        </div>

                        <nav id="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li onClick={() => this.setState({ activeCategory: portfolioData.web })} className="menu-item">Web</li>
                                <li onClick={() => this.setState({ activeCategory: portfolioData.print })} className="menu-item">Print</li>
                                <li onClick={() => this.setState({ activeCategory: portfolioData.photo })} className="menu-item">Photography</li>
                                <li onClick={() => this.setState({ activeCategory: portfolioData.contact })} className="menu-item">Contact</li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {mainContent}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

data.json

```
{
    "web": [
        {
            "name": "Web 1",
            "imagePath": "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
            "subContent": {
                "subTitle": "Cramer",
                "images": [
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg"
                ],
                "link": "www.cramer.com"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "Web 2",
            "imagePath": "../images/earx-thumb.jpg",
            "subContent": {
                "subTitle": "Cramer",
                "images": [
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg"
                ],
                "link": "www.cramer.com"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "Web 3",
            "imagePath": "../images/inlight-thumb.jpg",
            "subContent": {
                "subTitle": "Cramer",
                "images": [
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg"
                ],
                "link": "www.cramer.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "print": [
        {
            "name": "Print 1",
            "imagePath": "../images/earx-thumb.jpg",
            "subContent": {
                "subTitle": "Cramer",
                "images": [
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg"
                ],
                "link": "www.cramer.com"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "Print 2",
            "imagePath": "../images/inlight-thumb.jpg",
            "subContent": {
                "subTitle": "Cramer",
                "images": [
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg"
                ],
                "link": "www.cramer.com"
            }
        },{
            "name": "Print 3",
            "imagePath": "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
            "subContent": {
                "subTitle": "Cramer",
                "images": [
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg"
                ],
                "link": "www.cramer.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "photo": [
        {
            "name": "Photo 1",
            "imagePath": "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
            "subContent": {
                "subTitle": "Cramer",
                "images": [
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg"
                ],
                "link": "www.cramer.com"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "Photo 2",
            "imagePath": "../images/inlight-thumb.jpg",
            "subContent": {
                "subTitle": "Cramer",
                "images": [
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg"
                ],
                "link": "www.cramer.com"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "Photo 3",
            "imagePath": "../images/earx-thumb.jpg",
            "subContent": {
                "subTitle": "Cramer",
                "images": [
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg",
                    "../images/cramer-thumb.jpg"
                ],
                "link": "www.cramer.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "contact": {
        "name": "Cory Fitzpatrick",
        "bio": "I am Awesome!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start to split your app in component, 
for example a component header, content, contact,
and for your state, instead of having 4 different you just have the same onClick button who check the label of the li and then set a unique state of the content to show for example

Comment: Could you give me an example of that?

Comment: Sure,

for example you'll have your 3 different component in separate file like :

`class Header extends Components {...}
 class Content extends Components {...}
 class Contact extends Components {...}`

then in your parents components where you call this

`render(){
  <div>
    <ul>
        <li onClick={() => this.setState(labelToShow: 'Content')}>Content</li>
    <ul>
    {this.state.labelToShow === 'Content' ? <Content /> : null} // for example
  </div>
}`

Comment: Ok I get yah but I think I need to use props for this maybe and state for what data to use or vise versa?

Comment: you use props if you want to pass data to your child component but you only want to show them so you don't need